# Restrict access to webinar after registration in CiviEvent

Tags: wordpress, civievent

We are registering webinar participants through CiviCRM event pages, so each participant becomes a CiviCRM contact associated with one or more webinar-type events. Some of these webinars are paid events. Is there a good way to restrict access to a webinar based on the information in CiviCRM? We'd like to be able to restrict access so that only paid participants can access the paid webinars, even if someone else gets the webinar link, for instance.

We have not settled on a webinar platform yet, though we are leaning towards [Zoom](http://zoom.us). Another possibility is [Blackboard/Collaborate](http://www.blackboard.com/online-collaborative-learning/blackboard-collaborate.aspx).

Any thoughts/suggestions would be welcome.

WordPress 4.8.1

CiviCRM 4.7.21

Answer (score 1):

While integrations aren't hard to write for a coder, there are obviously a lot of webinar/CiviCRM integrations that haven't been written yet.  So if you're not interested in coding (or hiring a coder), I believe your two options are [GoToWebinar](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gotowebinar/blob/master/README.md) and [Moodle](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.civimoodle).